# Kubeclt error ( v1.14 to v1.16): error on migrating from v1.14 to v1.16

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have this very basic YAML file which i tried to migrate from kubectl v1.14 to v1.16. I changed `extensions/v1beta1` to `apps/v1` and I added selectors as well since they were mandatory in v1.16.

My original YAML file which worked fine in v1.14:

I modified the files for v1.16. My YAML files now look like this:

But on running this I get the following error

```
error: error validating "/root/config/cpx.yaml": 
error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template): 
unknown field "selector" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodTemplateSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): 
missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; 
if you choose to ignore these errors, 
turn validation off with --validate=false
```

What could be causing this issue? I followed all the steps in the kubectl depreciation manual ? It should ideally work in v1.16 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from `extensions/v1beta1` to `apps/v1` also requires informing the `selector` field, this is no longer inferred from the pod template.

- Notice the optional at the `extenstions/v1beta1` type: https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/5524a3672fbb1d8e9528811576c859dbedffeed7/extensions/v1beta1/types.go#L107-L110
- See that same block at the new `apps/v1` type: https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/5524a3672fbb1d8e9528811576c859dbedffeed7/apps/v1/types.go#L276-L279

Add a selector that matches your Pod template's label and you should be good.